# How to get these organ sounds

Tags: organ, vst

I'm a guitarist and keyboardist and try to do everything on my own when it comes to recording my music.

I'm a big fan of organs, however, there are some sounds I've never been able to achieve.

Two of them are in this song, one is right in the beginning, the other one can be heard at 3:43:

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve that sound, preferably with a free vsti? I also own the Zebra 2 synthesizer which has some great organs, I just can't get these particular sounds.

Thanks alot!

Michael

Answer (score 2):

The opening part of the song sounds to me like multiple tracks of monophonic guitar lines, each using some sustaining mechanism like an [ebow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBow) or [sustainiac](http://www.sustainiac.com/).

The bit at 3:43 sounds like a (possibly Hammond) organ going through a rotary (possibly Leslie) speaker. A search for Hammond organ VSTs might yield something useful. Alternatively you might be able to find a rotary speaker VST effect that would work with one of your existing organ sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try this pedal if you want to get your guitar to sound like an organ.

It does sound like there is some volume swells also so maybe a good volume pedal could also help.